# How to Sum and Group Union of Two Tables with Different Column Names in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below successfully returns credit card and check payments for a date range by vendor. I have been unable to write an outer select statement using the aliases to sum the Amount and group by Vendor. How can I do this query?

```
SELECT
BillPaymentCreditCard.PayeeEntityRefFullName as Vendor, BillPaymentCreditCard.Amount as Amount 
FROM
BillPaymentCreditCard NOSYNC 
WHERE
BillPaymentCreditCard.TxnDate >= {d'2014-01-01'} and BillPaymentCreditCard.TxnDate <= {d'2014-02-01'} 

UNION ALL

SELECT
BillPaymentCheck.PayeeEntityRefFullName as Vendor, BillPaymentCheck.Amount as Amount 
FROM
BillPaymentCheck NOSYNC 
WHERE 
BillPaymentCheck.TxnDate >= {d'2014-01-01'} and  BillPaymentCheck.TxnDate <= {d'2014-02-01'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. - Per comment - remove the nosync table hints.

```
SELECT Vendor, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM (

    SELECT BillPaymentCreditCard.PayeeEntityRefFullName as Vendor, BillPaymentCreditCard.Amount as Amount
    FROM BillPaymentCreditCard
    WHERE BillPaymentCreditCard.TxnDate >= {d'2014-01-01'}
         and BillPaymentCreditCard.TxnDate <= {d'2014-02-01'}

    UNION ALL

    SELECT BillPaymentCheck.PayeeEntityRefFullName as Vendor, BillPaymentCheck.Amount as Amount
    FROM BillPaymentCheck
    WHERE BillPaymentCheck.TxnDate >= {d'2014-01-01'}
         and BillPaymentCheck.TxnDate <= {d'2014-02-01'}
    ) AS Vendors
GROUP BY Vendor
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but I got an ODBC error "Unexpected extra token: Vendors" What could be causing this?

Comment: See my edit - NOSYNC table hints were causing the query to not execute in the local SSMS, and I imagine they were also causing problems with ODBC's parsing.

Comment: I missed removing the NOSYNC. I ran the query exactly as suggested this time. I got an "Unexpected extra token: AS" error this time. I removed the outer select and ran only the union, which worked just fine. I don't know if it matters but I am querying a linked server.

Comment: You can try removing the derived table alias, but this seems counter intuitive to me. At this point I think you might want to take this as a question to either here as an ODBC question, or to StackExchange's Database Administrator site. The issue you're experiencing with ODBC is beyond my knowledge at the moment.